# When creating a NuGet package, how do I specify a framework version for an assembly?

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I am attempting to create a NuGet package using NuGet core as part of a build process.  The build process creates specific framework versions, 3.5, 4.0, and 4.5.  How do I specify the framework version for each assembly?

```
public void Create(Package package)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(package.Id))
        throw new ArgumentException("package.Id is required", "package");

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(package.Version))
        throw new ArgumentException("package.Version is required", "package");

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(package.Authors))
        throw new ArgumentException("package.Authors is required", "package");

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(package.Description))
        throw new ArgumentException("package.Description is required", "package");

    if (package.Files == null || package.Files.Count == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("package.Files cannot be empty", "package");

    ManifestMetadata metadata = new ManifestMetadata();
    metadata.Id = package.Id;
    metadata.Version = package.Version;
    metadata.Title = package.Title;
    metadata.Authors = package.Authors;
    metadata.Owners = package.Authors;
    metadata.IconUrl = package.IconUrl;
    metadata.ProjectUrl = package.ProjectUrl;
    metadata.RequireLicenseAcceptance = true;
    metadata.LicenseUrl = package.LicenseUrl;
    metadata.Summary = package.Summary;
    metadata.Description = package.Description;
    metadata.Copyright = package.Copyright;
    metadata.Language = "en-US";
    metadata.Tags = package.Tags;
    metadata.ReleaseNotes = package.ReleaseNotes;

    List<ManifestFile> manifestFiles = new List<ManifestFile>();

    foreach (var file in package.Files)
    {
        ManifestFile manifestFile = new ManifestFile();
        manifestFile.Source = Path.GetFileName(file);
        manifestFile.Target = @"lib\" + Path.GetFileName(file);
        manifestFiles.Add(manifestFile);
    }

    PackageBuilder builder = new PackageBuilder();
    builder.PopulateFiles(ExtractPath(package.Files[0]), manifestFiles);
    builder.Populate(metadata);

    using (FileStream stream = File.Open(package.PackagePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        builder.Save(stream);
    }
}

private static string ExtractPath(string fullPath)
{
    if (fullPath.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("fullPath");

    //Account for already in form of path
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Path.GetFileName(fullPath))
        || String.IsNullOrEmpty(Path.GetExtension(fullPath)))
    {
        return fullPath;
    }

    return Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By convention, when defining a target you use the root directory and then the framework version.  This is outlined [here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package).

So in a nuspec file, you would see this for .NET 4.5:

```
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Release\MyAssembly.dll" target="lib\net45" />
  </files>
```

So when defining your target, just add the convention for the .NET version you are targeting:

```
var netVersion45 = "\net45";
foreach (var file in package.Files)
    {
        ManifestFile manifestFile = new ManifestFile();
        manifestFile.Source = Path.GetFileName(file);
        manifestFile.Target = @"lib\" + netVersion45;
        manifestFiles.Add(manifestFile);
    }
```